# THREE JS realistic render

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, gltf

I created scene on three js editor. And I also tryed to get same result with my project. I used R3F on my own project.

[My Project Scene Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8wOg.jpg)

[Three js editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzfE9.jpg)

On the threeJS editor if I increase the directional light intensity everything seems fine.
But in my project the lights have kind of a overexposure and the colors are overly saturated. Also shadow bias seems to work differently

And also when I try to enable shadows. I need to open cast and recieve shadows for same model.
After enable receive and cast shadow it causes noise effect.

[Noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVUsE.jpg)

I need to show my models as realistic as posible.

Comment: You'll probably want to enable some tone mapping on the renderer to reduce over-exposure and saturation.  Shadow bias and other parameters are used to avoid the 'noise' you see. But we only see screenshots here, and can't tell you what parameters to use. It's generally very important to share _reproducible_ problems, including complete and minimal code needed to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try enable tone mapping, and change outputEncoding. Some settings differ in versions of threeJS. But there is my settings for three 0.141.0 version.

```
renderer.toneMapping = ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding
```